# How to make a dialog unique to card

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

When I add a card to Inbox list, then I can double click on it and a dialog window pops up. In the dialog window I am able to pick out a date from the calender, put a string value to input field and create a dynamic checkbox. Then when I press the button (Get Value), the values appear on the card. This works fine. The problem comes when I add another card to the Inbox and I double click on it to open dialog window, the same values from the previous dialog window are shown. I don't want it. 
I want every time I add a new one card, and I double click on it, the dialog window is empty of values.

I think the solution might be to make the card unique, but I am not sure.

Please help me, and provide some code.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/17/)

HTML:

> ```
>     <!--Inbox list and button to add a card-->
>     <div id="inboxList" class="cellContainer">
>         <p style="display: inline">Inbox</p> 
>         <!--Button to add a Card-->
>         <input type="button" id="AddCardBtn" value="+ Add a Card..."/> <hr class="fancy-line"/> <br/>
>
>         <!--Card div-->
>         <div id="userAddedCard"> <br/>
>             <div>
>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </div>
>
>
> </div>
> <!--Modal Dialog-->
> <div id="modalDialog">
>
>     <form>
>         <label>Title</label>
>         <input type="text" id="customTextBox" value="some value"/>
>         <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" value="some date"/></p> 
>         <input type="button" id="Getbtn" value="Get value"/> <hr/><br/>
>
>         <label>Add checkBox</label>
>         <br />
>         <div id="progressbar"></div>
>         <br />
>         <input type="text" id="checkBoxName" />
>         <input type="button" id="btnSaveCheckBox" value="_Ok" />
>         <br />
>
>     </form>
>
> </div>
> <!--Reference to Jquery-->
> ```

Jquery:

> ```
> $(function () {
>     // Click function to add a card
>     var $div = $('<div />').addClass('sortable-div'); 
>     $('<label>Title</label><br/>').appendTo($div);              
>     $('<input/>', { "type": "text","class":"ctb"}).appendTo($div);
>     $('<input/>', { "type": "text","class":"date"}).appendTo($div);
>     var cnt =0,$currentTarget;
>     $('#AddCardBtn').click(function () {
>       var $newDiv = $div.clone(true);
>       cnt++;  
>       $newDiv.prop("id","div"+cnt);  
>       $('#userAddedCard').append($newDiv);
>
>     });
>
>     // Double click to open Modal Dialog Window
>     $('#userAddedCard').dblclick(function (e) {
>         $currentTarget = $(e.target);
>
>         $('#modalDialog').dialog({
>             modal: true,
>             height: 600,
>             width: 500,
>             position: 'center'
>         });
>         return false;
>
>     });
>     $("#datepicker").datepicker({showWeek:true, firstDay:1});
>
>     $("#Getbtn").on("click",function() {
>       var val = $("#customTextBox").val();
>       $currentTarget.find(".ctb").val(val);
>       $currentTarget.find(".date").val($("#datepicker").val() );
>       $('#modalDialog').dialog("close");
>     });
>
>     // Add a new checkBox
>     $('#btnSaveCheckBox').click(function () {
>         addCheckbox($('#checkBoxName').val());
>         $('#checkBoxName').val("");
>     });
>
>     function addCheckbox(name) {
>         var container = $('#modalDialog');
>         var inputs = container.find('input');
>         var id = inputs.length + 1;
>
>         $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'cb' + id, value: name }).appendTo(container);
>         $('<label />', { 'for': 'cb' + id, text: name }).appendTo(container);
>         $('<br/>').appendTo(container);
>
>
>     }    
> });
> ```

Comment: "Please help me, and provide some code.".. We don't provide some code for you. You have to learn about it. Asking for code is always a bad practice.

Comment: I have tried by my self, but I have no idea how to do it. I am not agree that asking for code is always a bad practice. I always learn something.

Comment: Do you have any idea to solve the issue ??

Comment: In someway you need to give every card a unique class/id.

Comment: Do you have some links, how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
for your code add the lines that i added
$(function () {
// Click function to add a card
var $div = $('<div />').addClass('sortable-div'); 
$('<label>Title</label><br/>').appendTo($div);              
$('<input/>', { "type": "text","class":"ctb"}).appendTo($div);
$('<input/>', { "type": "text","class":"date"}).appendTo($div);
var cnt =0,$currentTarget;
$('#AddCardBtn').click(function () {
  var $newDiv = $div.clone(true);
  cnt++;  
  $newDiv.prop("id","div"+cnt);  
  $('#userAddedCard').append($newDiv);
```

//      alert($('#userAddedCard').find("div.sortable-div").length);
    });

```
// Double click to open Modal Dialog Window
$('#userAddedCard').dblclick(function (e) {
    $currentTarget = $(e.target);

    $('#modalDialog').dialog({
        modal: true,
        height: 600,
        width: 500,
        position: 'center'
    });
    return false;

});
$("#datepicker").datepicker({showWeek:true, firstDay:1});

$("#Getbtn").on("click",function() {
  var val = $("#customTextBox").val();
  $currentTarget.find(".ctb").val(val);
  $currentTarget.find(".date").val($("#datepicker").val() );
    document.getElementById('customTextBox').value="";//add this line
    document.getElementById('datepicker').value="";//add this line
    $('.allcheckbox').remove();//add this line
  $('#modalDialog').dialog("close");
});

// Add a new checkBox
$('#btnSaveCheckBox').click(function () {
    addCheckbox($('#checkBoxName').val());
    $('#checkBoxName').val("");
});

function addCheckbox(name) {
    var container = $('#modalDialog');
    var inputs = container.find('input');
    var id = inputs.length + 1;

    $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', class: 'allcheckbox', id: 'cb' + id, value: name }).appendTo(container);//add the attribute class
    $('<label />', { 'for': 'cb' + id, class: 'allcheckbox', text: name }).appendTo(container);//add the attribute class
    $('<br/>').appendTo(container);


}
```

});

Comment: I still have the same problem.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I'm sorry, I didn't see it. I want to, when I double click the card and pick out a date from the calender, put a string value to input field and create a dynamic checkbox. Then, after closing the dialog, and double clicking again on the same card, I want the same values to be shown in this dialog, but the problem is that it is empty when I double click on it.  Later, when I add a new card, I want the dialog to be empty. Do you understand what I mean?